# Correct format to specify the ipv6 address in '/etc/hosts' file

Tags: ipv6, hosts

I have configured a server with Gentoo 64 bits that it has IPv4 and IPv6 and they are working well.
But I don't know how specify the IPv6 of the server in `/etc/hosts` file. **With or without "/64" final?**:

```
...
ipv4.XXX.XXX.XXX nsXXXXXXX.ip-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu 
ipv6:XXxX:XX:xxxX::/64 nsXXXXXXX.ip-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu
....
```

or

```
....
ipv4.XXX.XXX.XXX nsXXXXXXX.ip-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu 
ipv6:XXxX:XX:xxxX:: nsXXXXXXX.ip-XXX-XXX-XXX.eu
....
```

?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.